# RunKeeper button mashed next to Twitter text

Tags: bug, status-completed

I just posted an answer, and the RunKeeper button shows up on the social sharing links, but the Twitter text is mismatched with the RunKeeper button.

[image: Twitter text and RunKeeper button mismatch]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Totally my bug - this will be fixed shortly.